# Angular-gantt can't import it in my application

Tags: angular, angular-gantt

I'm trying to integrate angular-gantt to a current application 
I follow https://angular-gantt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/

Installed it like this:

```
yarn add angular-gantt --save
```

After I launch my application I get an error like this:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

> 'gantt-tree' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'gantt-tree' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'gantt-tree' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>   column-magnet="options.columnMagnet">
>                                               [ERROR ->]

I import it like this

```
// Import your library
import { GanttService, GanttComponent, GanttActivityComponent, GanttFooterComponent,
GanttHeaderComponent } from 'angular-gantt';
```

Comment: Are you integrating angular-gantt in an non angular html page? What javascript framework are you using

Comment: i m using typescript, and a project on angular 4 
i m tryining to use it on a .ts file

Answer (score 0):

The `angular-gantt` library can only be used with angularJS (which is version 1.x) but not with any Angular2+.

for angular 2+ you might want to try [ng2-gantt](https://github.com/sameh-g/ng2-gantt) instead